# How to create a localDb with mdf file inside the project directory?

Tags: entity-framework, edmx, localdb

I tried to get started with LocalDb and got few problem. I created a new LocalDb using EF Generate Database Wizard and if I created a new database, it saved the mdf file inside user profile. If I manually created mdf and chosed 'Attach a database file' option, edmx.sql cannot be executed. I would like to have my localdb inside the project directory and everything else (EF, .Net membership identity) still be working fine.

I have also tried putting `AttachDbFilename=MyDataFile.mdf` to the connecting string but when i run edmx.sql, i got an error saying mdf cannot be found. It is still searching in user profile directory.

I don't have SSMS installed on my machine. I am using VS2013 Pro.

Updated:

```
<add name="DeveloperNetworkContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DeveloperNetwork.csdl|res://*/DeveloperNetwork.ssdl|res://*/DeveloperNetwork.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DeveloperNetworkDb.mdf;initial catalog=DeveloperNetworkDb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
GO
USE [DeveloperNetworkDb];
GO
IF SCHEMA_ID(N'dbo') IS NULL EXECUTE(N'CREATE SCHEMA [dbo]');
GO
```

Comment: Errr, I too am looking for a way to do this. However, I can't tell if your above update is an answer to your own question. If it is, I can't make head nor tail of it!

Comment: Hi @stigzler i can't remember much now but it looks like that probably how i fixed it. As I don't use MSSql anymore now and moved to Mongo mainly so I can't tell you how to do this. Even for EF, you don't need those metadata anymore in new version of EF Core I think. You can use normal Sql connection.